# Netbeans wizard for JSF pages doesn't recognize TomEE 1.6 to have Web Profile support

Tags: netbeans, apache-tomee

I am creating a Java EE 6 application with the help of Netbeans 8.0 and TomEE 1.6. I have successfully added the server to netbeans and even generated some entity classes. I am currenlty trying to generate some JSF pages using the Netbeans wizard. However I get the following message

> Cannot be generated for Java EE 6 sources wihtout server with complete Java EE 6 Web profile support (at least EJB Lite support).

I am using TomEE 1.6.0.2 plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Netbeans 8 has a bug in which it fails to find the `tomee-common-[version].jar in the [TomEE]/lib` directory.

The solution is to simply rename the jar file to an older version.

For example, you have `[TomEE]/lib/tomee-common-1.6.0.2.jar` or `[TomEE]/lib/tomee-common-1.7.1.jar`. Rename these files to [`TomEE]/lib/tomee-common-1.6.0.jar`

This should sort you out :)

Comment: I have a suspicion that the bug has been fixed in NB 8.1. Meanwhile I have been using GSF and I just created a new project to check you r solution and the problem has disappeared. I will accept it

Comment: The bug is also presented in NB 8.0.1 as this is the version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tomcatEE 1.7.2 with a few small changes
you find here:

http://zarnisfd.blogspot.com/

I think this also applies to TomEE 1.6

Answer (score -1):

According to the following sites:

http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic48005.html

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210835

Tomcat does not support EJB's therefor you would need to use an enterprise server that at least supports EJB Lite. One such server would be [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/)

Comment: I don't need EJB support and that's why I was looking for TomEE

Comment: Oh okay. That wasn't specified in the question.